# How to catch NSError instance thrown in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, rubymotion

I am developing an `iOS` application with Rubymotion which worked pretty fine until i added a new `UIViewController`. I have added the controller via xcode and have got just a `UITextField` as an element in it. On running the simulator and on displaying this particular scene, I get an instance of `NSError`. I also dont see the `UITextField` element in my screen.

Can any one please explain as to what it is and how do i handle the `NSError` and make sense out of it?

Any help at this point would be of great help.

**UPDATE**: I am getting the NSError instance every time my app is launched first, no matter what the controller is. I had upgraded to Xcode 5.1 yesterday. Wonder if that has something to do with the error.

**UPDATE 2**: This was result of a confusion on my part. I had assumed the NSError to have been raised after upgrading to Xcode 5.1 and thought it was some bug. The reason being was that I had had started using push notifications at the same time as I had upgraded to 5.1. As push notifications don't work in simulators, the NSError was being returned by the simulator. Messed it up big time and spent quite a few hours trying to debug this problem.

Comment: I get something like this '#<NSError:0xd68beb0>'( an instance of NSError ) in my console when I run the simulator. If I can get some useful info out of that is my concern here.

Comment: Does the app terminate?

Comment: No, the app doesn't terminate.

Comment: Everything worked fine until you upgraded to Xcode 5.1?

Comment: Maybe you could try and turn on exception breakpoint to se if some exception throws that is then captured and handled with a NSError instead. Click breakpoints in the left panel and then '+' sign and add exception breakpoint.

Comment: why dont you uplaod your code to dropbox or somewhere, and post its link here. so we can check it.

Comment: Yes, eveything worked fine until xcode 5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSError` is a class and it is used as the preferred way to handle errors in objective-c. Usually it works like this: 
You declare a `NSError` pointer and sends the address to that one in as a parameter to a method that might fail. If something goes wrong in the method a `NSError` object is created and populated with info about the error and when the methods returns you can check the error object to se if anything went wrong.

```
NSError *error;
[someObject someFunctionWithParam:paramOne andError:&error];
if ( error ) {
    // Here you can inspect the error and act accordingly
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

If you are the one implementing a method it usually looks something like this.

```
- (void)someFunctionWithParameter:(NSString *)argOne andError:(NSError **)error {
    // something goes wrong
    *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"SomeDomain" code:500 userInfo:@{@"infoKey": @"some info"}];
}
```

So about the title of your question. There is no catching `NSError`'s since they are not thrown. Only exceptions are thrown.

Comment: Whats happening here is that when i run the simulator, I get something like this '#<NSError:0xd68beb0>' in my console. My problem is if I can make some sensible reading out of that.

Comment: It is common practice for methods that return errors to always have a return argument as well, so you should check that you get nothing back instead of checking for an error. See for example `-(id)initWithData:(NSData *)data error:(NSError **)outError` which returns `id` and `-(BOOL)setInputGain:(float)gain error:(NSError **)outError` which is a setter so it has no real return value (but returns a BOOL) so that you can still check the return value instead of the error)

Comment: Yes, but what info do I make out of this NSError instance logged in the console? There's barely anything I can do with it.

Comment: Just NSLog() the description and the userInfo. If they were set (all Apple classes do that, if you create your own error I recommend doing the same) you can easily log them via `NSLog(@"Error: %@, UserInfo: %@", [error description], [error userInfo]);` that info can also be displayed in an alert view.